# Python code runs in Thonny correctly but does not work in terminal

Tags: python, terminal

I have a code that gets a one or a 0 from the user and will turn an LED on if 1, off if 0. It runs perfect when I run it in the Thonny IDE on the Pi itself. But when I try to run it through putty or even the Pi's terminal it will run everything except the if statements. (Does not print 'LED On/Off' or actually turn on or off the LED).

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time


LEDPin = 17

#Setup
def setup():
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) #Set GPIO to BCM numbering
    GPIO.setup(LEDPin,GPIO.OUT,initial = GPIO.LOW)
    print('setup complete')

def main():
    setup()
    while 1: #check for keyboard input
        KBInput = input('1 for LED On, 0 for LED Off: ')
        if KBInput == '1':
            GPIO.output(LEDPin,GPIO.HIGH)
            print('LED On ')
        if KBInput == '0':
            GPIO.output(LEDPin,GPIO.LOW)
            print('LED Off ')

try:
    main()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\n\nGoodbye')
    GPIO.output(LEDPin,GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out. For some reason in the IDE the keyboard input is received as a string, where as in the terminal it is received as an int. So i just needed to make the line like the following to work on both. It will also work through Putty.

`if KBInput == '1' or KBInput == 1:`

Comment: This means, you used Python 2 in the Terminal. Thonny uses Python 3.

Comment: Is there a way to make sure it uses Python 3 in the terminal?

Comment: How did you run the code in the terminal? The command `python` uses Python 2 and `python3` uses Python 3.

Comment: Turned out @aivar's comment was the solution to my issue similar to the OP